# Prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} = \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $ and $A = (a_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n}$ is a $n 
>  \times n$ matrix.
>
> Suppose $a_{i1} + a_{i2} + ... + a_{in} = \lambda $.
>
> For all $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I started by making the sum of the first row so I can use:   $a_{i1} + a_{i2} + ... + a_{in} = \lambda $.

$\begin{align} \det(A - \lambda I_n)= \begin{vmatrix} 
a_{11} - \lambda & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & &  \\
a_{n1} & \dots & & a_{nn} - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix} 
\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{1j} - \lambda & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & &  \\
a_{n1} & \dots & & a_{nn} - \lambda
\end{vmatrix} =
 \begin{vmatrix} 
0 & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & &  \\
a_{n1} & \dots & & a_{nn} - \lambda
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}$

I don't see how to proceed to prove the sum of $a_{1j}$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Can you compute the eigenvectors of $\pmatrix{1 & 4\\ 2 & 3}$? Notice anything?

Comment: @JohnHughes The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $5$. To get the eigenvectors I need to solve the two systems. I'm sorry, I didn't notice anything. What am I missing?

Comment: That the eigenvector for $5$ consists of all 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: see what happens when $A$ is multiplied on the right with a column vector of $1$.

Comment: I will get $ A. \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} \lambda \\ \lambda \\ \vdots \\ \lambda \end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Which proves $\lambda $ is an eivenvalue. What if I wanted to get the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$? Thank you.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi You just found one. Any scalar multiplier of it yields another. It's not clear to me at the moment if these constitute ** all ** the eigenvectors for eigenvalue $1$, but that's not part of the original question, is it? Another user can help you with this extra bit.

Comment: No. I am asked to find an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue. That answered my question, thank you.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi In the previous comment, I should have said "eigenvalue $\lambda$." In any case, you're welcome and I'm glad the question is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

you can use induction.
for $n=1$ is abvious, for $n=2 $ you have :

$ \pmatrix{b & a\\ c & d} $ with $ a+b=c+d=K$

so for finding eigenvalue you have to make the determinant of $\pmatrix{a-x & b\\ c & d-x}$ equal zero. i.e

$$(a-x)(d-x)-cb=0$$ $$ad-ax-xd+x^{2}-cb=0$$, we have b=K-a and c=K-d so

$$ad-ax-xd+x^{2}-(K-a)(K-d)$$ so 
$$ad-ax-xd+Kd+aK-ad-K^{2}+x^{2}=0$$, so

$$ K=x $$ is eigenvalue .

now you should assume its true for a $n \times n$ matrix , and prove for $ n+1\times n+1$ . it is very easy